# Can I use two character vectors in a sqldf join statement?

Tags: r, sqldf

I am conducting a `sqldf` join of 3 different data.tables. My current working code looks like this:

```
AltSuitRaw <- data.table(sqldf('select RealAlt.*, SpdSpSuit * SpdSpT as SpdSpSuitT, SpdIncSuit * SpdIncT as SpdIncSuitT, SpdGrowSuit * SpdGrT as SpdGrowSuitT,
        RzbSpSuit * RzbSpT as RzbSpSuitT, RzbIncSuit * RzbIncT as RzbIncSuitT, RzbGrowSuit * RzbGrT as RzbGrowSuitT,
        FMSSpSuit * FmsSpT as FmsSpSuitT, FMSIncSuit * FmsIncT as FmsIncSuitT, FMSGrowSuit * FMSGrT as FmsGrowSuitT,
        BhsSpSuit * BhsSpT as BhsSpSuitT, BhsIncSuit * BhsIncT as BhsIncSuitT, BhsGrowSuit * BhsGrT as BhsGrowSuitT,
        BrtSpSuit * BRTsp as BrtSpSuitT, BrtIncSuit * BRTinc as BrtIncSuitT, BrtGrSuit * BRTgr as BrtGrowSuitT,
        CcfSpSuit * CCFsp as CcfSpSuitT, CcfIncSuit * CCFinc as CcfIncSuitT, CcfGrSuit * Ccfgr as CcfGrowSuitT,
        GsfSpSuit * GSFsp as GsfSpSuitT, GsfIncSuit * GSFinc as GsfIncSuitT, GsfGrSuit * GSFgr as GsfGrowSuitT,
        RbtSpSuit * RBTsp as RbtSpSuitT, RbtIncSuit * RBTinc as RbtIncSuitT, RbtGrSuit * RBTgr as RbtGrowSuitT,
        SmbSpSuit * SMBsp as SmbSpSuitT, SmbIncSuit * SMBinc as SmbIncSuitT, SmbGrSuit * SMBgr as SmbGrowSuitT,
        StbSpSuit * STBsp as StbSpSuitT, StbIncSuit * STBinc as StbIncSuitT, StbGrSuit * STBgr as StbGrowSuitT,
        HbcSpSuit * HBCsp as HbcSpSuitT, HbcIncSuit * HBCinc as HbcIncSuitT, HbcGrSuit * HBCgr as HbcGrowSuitT,
        AtActSuit * ATha as AtActSuitT, AtInfSuit * ATinf as AtInfSuitT,
        LcActSuit * LCha as LcActSuitT, LcInfSuit * LCha as LcInfSuitT,
        TnActSuit * TNha as TnActSuitT, TnInfSuit * TNinf as TnInfSuitT,
        WdActSuit * WDha as WdActSuitT, WdInfSuit * WDinf as WdInfSuitT
        from RealAlt 
        left join SpecSuitTemp using (Temp)
        left join AltSuitDates using (Month)'))
```

As you can see this is very large, and in my opinion, unwieldy chunk of code. A small change in the column names of either SpecSuitTemp or AltSuitDates would break the above code. What I was hoping to do is to do the join using a character vector of the column names so that if they change it doesn't matter, something like the following:

```
AltSuitRawt <- data.table(sqldf('select RealAlt.*, SpecSuitTemp[tcoln] * AltSuitDates[dcoln] as newcn from RealAlt left join SpecSuitTemp using (Temp) left join AltSuitDates using (Month)'))
```

Where

```
newcn <- paste0(names(SpecSuitTemp),"T"); newcn <- newcn[-1]
tcoln <- names(SpecSuitTemp); tcoln <- tcoln[-1]
dcoln <- names(AltSuitDates); dcoln <- dcoln[-1]
```

However this statement doesn't work. I do not know `sql` but was able to get the large statement above to work, with a lot of help from a coworker.

My question is, can I conduct a `sqldf` join statement using character vectors of the column names? I was thinking maybe I should wrap my statement with an `lapply` but not sure if that is possible. Any help, resources, or suggestions are appreciated.

Dput of my data:

```
RealAlt <- structure(list(Alternative = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), TraceID = c("h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1"), WaterYear = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Location = c("GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD"), Temp = c(9.8, 8.7, 8.5, 8.5, 8.9, 9.3, 9.8, 10.8, 11.2, 11.6, 11.3, 11.3, 10.1, 8.6, 8.1, 9.1, 9.5, 10.1, 10.7, 11.6)), .Names = c("Alternative", "TraceID", "WaterYear", "Month", "Location", "Temp"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
SpecSuitTemp <- structure(list(Temp = c(8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12), SpdSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SpdIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SpdGrowSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RzbSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RzbIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RzbGrowSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FMSSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FMSIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FMSGrowSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BhsSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BhsIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BhsGrowSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BrtSpSuit = c(0.333333333, 0.366666667, 0.4, 0.433333333, 0.466666667, 0.5, 0.533333333, 0.566666667, 0.6, 0.633333333, 0.666666667, 0.7, 0.733333333, 0.766666667, 0.8, 0.833333333, 0.866666667, 0.9, 0.933333333, 0.966666667, 1, 0.975, 0.95, 0.925, 0.9, 0.875, 0.85, 0.825, 0.8, 0.775, 0.75, 0.725, 0.7, 0.675, 0.65, 0.625, 0.6, 0.575, 0.55, 0.525, 0.5), BrtIncSuit = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.95, 0.94, 0.93, 0.92, 0.91, 0.9, 0.89, 0.88, 0.87, 0.86, 0.85, 0.84, 0.83, 0.82, 0.81, 0.8), BrtGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CcfSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CcfIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CcfGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GsfSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GsfIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GsfGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RbtSpSuit = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 0.966666667, 0.933333333, 0.9, 0.866666667, 0.833333333, 0.8, 0.766666667, 0.733333333, 0.7, 0.666666667, 0.633333333, 0.6, 0.566666667, 0.533333333, 0.5, 0.466666667, 0.433333333, 0.4, 0.366666667, 0.333333333), RbtIncSuit = c(0.333333333, 0.366666667, 0.4, 0.433333333, 0.466666667, 0.5, 0.533333333, 0.566666667, 0.6, 0.633333333, 0.666666667, 0.7, 0.733333333, 0.766666667, 0.8, 0.833333333, 0.866666667, 0.9, 0.933333333, 0.966666667, 1, 0.98, 0.96, 0.94, 0.92, 0.9, 0.88, 0.86, 0.84, 0.82, 0.8, 0.78, 0.76, 0.74, 0.72, 0.7, 0.68, 0.66, 0.64, 0.62, 0.6), RbtGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SmbSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SmbIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SmbGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), StbSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), StbIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), StbGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HbcSpSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HbcIncSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HbcGrSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AtActSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AtInfSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LcActSuit = c(0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LcInfSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TnActSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TnInfSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WdActSuit = c(1, 0.95, 0.9, 0.85, 0.8, 0.75, 0.7, 0.65, 0.6, 0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WdInfSuit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.033333333, 0.066666667, 0.1, 0.133333333, 0.166666667, 0.2, 0.233333333, 0.266666667, 0.3, 0.333333333)), .Names = c("Temp", "SpdSpSuit", "SpdIncSuit", "SpdGrowSuit", "RzbSpSuit", "RzbIncSuit", "RzbGrowSuit", "FMSSpSuit", "FMSIncSuit", "FMSGrowSuit", "BhsSpSuit", "BhsIncSuit", "BhsGrowSuit", "BrtSpSuit", "BrtIncSuit", "BrtGrSuit", "CcfSpSuit", "CcfIncSuit", "CcfGrSuit", "GsfSpSuit", "GsfIncSuit", "GsfGrSuit", "RbtSpSuit", "RbtIncSuit", "RbtGrSuit", "SmbSpSuit", "SmbIncSuit", "SmbGrSuit", "StbSpSuit", "StbIncSuit", "StbGrSuit", "HbcSpSuit", "HbcIncSuit", "HbcGrSuit", "AtActSuit", "AtInfSuit", "LcActSuit", "LcInfSuit", "TnActSuit", "TnInfSuit", "WdActSuit", "WdInfSuit"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -41L))
AltSuitDates <- data.table(structure(list(Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L,12L), SpdSpT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), SpdIncT = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), SpdGrT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), RzbSpT = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA,NA, NA, NA), RzbIncT = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA,NA), RzbGrT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FmsSpT = c(NA,NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FmsIncT = c(NA, NA, 1L,1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FMSGrT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BhsSpT = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA,NA), BhsIncT = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), BhsGrT = c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BRTsp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA,NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), BRTinc = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA,1L, 1L, 1L), BRTgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CCFsp = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), CCFinc = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), CCFgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), GSFsp = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L,NA, NA, NA), GSFinc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), GSFgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), RBTsp = c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), RBTinc = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), RBTgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L), SMBsp = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), SMBinc = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), SMBgr = c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), STBsp = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), STBinc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L,NA, NA, NA), STBgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HBCsp = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), HBCinc = c(NA,NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), HBCgr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ATha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L), ATinf = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), LCha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), LCinf = c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), TNha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), TNinf = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L), WDha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),WDinf = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Month","SpdSpT", "SpdIncT", "SpdGrT", "RzbSpT", "RzbIncT", "RzbGrT","FmsSpT", "FmsIncT", "FMSGrT", "BhsSpT", "BhsIncT", "BhsGrT","BRTsp", "BRTinc", "BRTgr", "CCFsp", "CCFinc", "CCFgr", "GSFsp","GSFinc", "GSFgr", "RBTsp", "RBTinc", "RBTgr", "SMBsp", "SMBinc","SMBgr", "STBsp", "STBinc", "STBgr", "HBCsp", "HBCinc", "HBCgr","ATha", "ATinf", "LCha", "LCinf", "TNha", "TNinf", "WDha", "WDinf"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**Edit: Added Expected output data**

```
AltSuitRaw <- data.table(structure(list(Alternative = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),TraceID = c("h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1","h00s1"), WaterYear = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L,2013L), Month = 1:6, Location = c("GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD","GCD", "GCD"), Temp = c(9.8, 8.7, 8.5, 8.5, 8.9, 9.3), SpdSpSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0"), SpdIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"0.0"), SpdGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RzbSpSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), RzbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA,"0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), RzbGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),FmsSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA), FmsIncSuitT = c(NA,NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA), FmsGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0), BhsSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), BhsIncSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), BhsGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0), BrtSpSuitT = c(0.933333333, 0.566666667, 0.5, NA,NA, NA), BrtIncSuitT = c(0.9, 0.35, 0.25, 0.25, NA, NA),BrtGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CcfSpSuitT = c(NA, NA,NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0"), CcfIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0","0.0"), CcfGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GsfSpSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0"), GsfIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,"0.0", "0.0"), GsfGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RbtSpSuitT = c(0.9,0.35, 0.25, 0.25, 0.45, 0.65), RbtIncSuitT = c(0.933333333,0.566666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.633333333, 0.766666667), RbtGrowSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SmbSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0","0.0"), SmbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"),SmbGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), StbSpSuitT = c(NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, "0.0"), StbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0"), StbGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HbcSpSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), HbcIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA,"0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), HbcGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),AtActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AtInfSuitT = c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0), LcActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LcInfSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TnActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TnInfSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WdActSuitT = c(0.1, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75, 0.55,0.35), WdInfSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Alternative","TraceID", "WaterYear", "Month", "Location", "Temp", "SpdSpSuitT","SpdIncSuitT", "SpdGrowSuitT", "RzbSpSuitT", "RzbIncSuitT", "RzbGrowSuitT","FmsSpSuitT", "FmsIncSuitT", "FmsGrowSuitT", "BhsSpSuitT", "BhsIncSuitT","BhsGrowSuitT", "BrtSpSuitT", "BrtIncSuitT", "BrtGrowSuitT","CcfSpSuitT", "CcfIncSuitT", "CcfGrowSuitT", "GsfSpSuitT", "GsfIncSuitT","GsfGrowSuitT", "RbtSpSuitT", "RbtIncSuitT", "RbtGrowSuitT","SmbSpSuitT", "SmbIncSuitT", "SmbGrowSuitT", "StbSpSuitT", "StbIncSuitT","StbGrowSuitT", "HbcSpSuitT", "HbcIncSuitT", "HbcGrowSuitT","AtActSuitT", "AtInfSuitT", "LcActSuitT", "LcInfSuitT", "TnActSuitT","TnInfSuitT", "WdActSuitT", "WdInfSuitT"), class = c("data.table","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to G. Grothendieck I was able to answer this question fully**

```
tcoln <- names(SpecSuitTemp)[-1]
dcoln <- names(AltSuitDates)[-1]
newcn <- toString(paste0(tcoln, " * ", dcoln, " as ", tcoln, "T"))

AltSuitRaw <- data.table(fn$sqldf('select RealAlt.*, $newcn from RealAlt left join SpecSuitTemp using (Temp) left join AltSuitDates using (Month)'))
```

Adding in the statement `RealAlt.*,` before `$newcn` gives me this output:

```
AltSuitRawt <- data.table(structure(list(Alternative = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A", "A"), TraceID = c("h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1","h00s1", "h00s1", "h00s1", "h20s3", "h20s3", "h20s3"), WaterYear = c(2013L,2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2034L, 2034L, 2034L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L), Location = c("GCD","GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "GCD", "RM225", "RM225", "RM225"), Temp = c(9.8, 8.7, 8.5, 8.5, 8.9, 9.3, 9.8, 14.7, 12.9, 10.9), SpdSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA), SpdIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA,NA), SpdGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3375, 0.1125, 0),RzbSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA,NA), RzbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA,NA, NA, NA), RzbGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.116666667,0, 0), FMSSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA), FMSIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA,NA, NA, NA, NA), FMSGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.116666667,0, 0), BhsSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA,NA, NA, NA), BhsIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0",NA, NA, NA, NA), BhsGrowSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0), BrtSpSuitT = c(0.933333333, 0.566666667, 0.5, NA,NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.275, 0.775), BrtIncSuitT = c(0.9, 0.35,0.25, 0.25, NA, NA, NA, 0.53, 0.71, 0.91), BrtGrSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.3, 0), CcfSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA,NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA), CcfIncSuitT = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA), CcfGrSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GsfSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA), GsfIncSuitT = c(NA, NA,NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA), GsfGrSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RbtSpSuitT = c(0.9, 0.35, 0.25,0.25, 0.45, 0.65, 0.9, NA, NA, NA), RbtIncSuitT = c(0.933333333,0.566666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.633333333, 0.766666667, 0.933333333,NA, NA, NA), RbtGrSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.675, 0.225,0), SmbSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0",NA, NA, NA), SmbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0","0.0", NA, NA, NA), SmbGrSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0), StbSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", NA,NA, NA), StbIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0",NA, NA, NA), StbGrSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),HbcSpSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA,NA), HbcIncSuitT = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", NA,NA, NA, NA), HbcGrSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.175, 0,0), AtActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AtInfSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LcActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LcInfSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), TnActSuitT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TnInfSuitT = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WdActSuitT = c(0.1, 0.65, 0.75,0.75, 0.55, 0.35, 0.1, 0, 0, 0), WdInfSuitT = c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Alternative", "TraceID","WaterYear", "Month", "Location", "Temp", "SpdSpSuitT", "SpdIncSuitT","SpdGrowSuitT", "RzbSpSuitT", "RzbIncSuitT", "RzbGrowSuitT","FMSSpSuitT", "FMSIncSuitT", "FMSGrowSuitT", "BhsSpSuitT", "BhsIncSuitT","BhsGrowSuitT", "BrtSpSuitT", "BrtIncSuitT", "BrtGrSuitT", "CcfSpSuitT","CcfIncSuitT", "CcfGrSuitT", "GsfSpSuitT", "GsfIncSuitT", "GsfGrSuitT","RbtSpSuitT", "RbtIncSuitT", "RbtGrSuitT", "SmbSpSuitT", "SmbIncSuitT","SmbGrSuitT", "StbSpSuitT", "StbIncSuitT", "StbGrSuitT", "HbcSpSuitT","HbcIncSuitT", "HbcGrSuitT", "AtActSuitT", "AtInfSuitT", "LcActSuitT","LcInfSuitT", "TnActSuitT", "TnInfSuitT", "WdActSuitT", "WdInfSuitT"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Using `all.equal` the two `data.tables` are equal except for some column header name mismatches based on whether or not some of the name is capitalized or not.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing out the long selection portion generate it into `sel` as shown:

```
library(sqldf)

nms1 <- names(SpecSuitTemp)[-1]
nms2 <- names(AltSuitDates)[-1]
sel <- toString(paste0(nms1, " * ", nms2, " as ", nms1, "T"))

fn$sqldf('select $sel 
          from RealAlt 
          left join SpecSuitTemp using (Temp)
          left join AltSuitDates using (Month)')
```

Comment: This almost gets me there. It exactly matches, using `all.equal`, the last 41 columns of AltSuitRaw but is missing the first 6. I will think about this and see if I can't get a full solution from your code, thanks.

Comment: I added an answer that built off your code. Thank you for your help. The functions `toString`, `fn$`, and `$variable` inside of `fn$sqldf` are quite useful; I definitely need to look into those more.