# Use values in df column to create a sql query

Tags: r, sqldf

I would like to take the values from a data frame and paste them into a text string that can be used as a sql query.  In SAS I would do it

```
proc sql noprint; Select Names into :names separated by ", " from df; quit;
```

this would create a variable &name storing all the names. Like: Id, Name, Account.  I would like to do this same type of thing in R, but do not know how.  I can create a vector with names separated by comma and each one is surrounded by quotes, I can take away the quotes using noquote function and have them in a vector, but I can not get the elements in another paste statement to add the "SELECT" and FROM. I can not get it to all paste.  Is there a way to pull the values on Column and create a text string that can be used as a SQL query inside R? Here is what I have tried in R:

```
name = c("Id", "IsDeleted", "Name", "Credit__Loan__c")
label = c("Record Id", "Deleted", "ID", "Loan")
df = data.frame(name, label)
names(df) <- c("name", "label")

as.query.fields = noquote(paste(df$name, collaspe=", "))
as.query.final <- paste("SELECT " , noquote(paste(df$name, collaspe=", ")), " id FROM Credit_Amortization_Schedule__c")
```

Comment: I think the `whisker` or `brew` packages will be helpful here.

Comment: Don't know if you have realized, but you have `collapse` spelled incorrectly (you have `collaspe`), and this affects the final result. You don't need the `noquote` function (it only affects the way objects are printed) and you can pass the `as.query.final` object directly in the call of `sqlQuery` (or similar functions) to execute the query.

Comment: Yes thanks for catching the spelling. That was just a typo and not the issue.  Also, I am using R to query Salesforce (using rforcecom and soql) so I really need to control the creation of the Select statement, so the sqlQuery from as.query.final does not work.  The only thing I can do is use the cat method to screen and copy and paste the result and then remove the trailing comma before the from statement. Alas in my laziness I was hoping to be able to fully automate it but I can not. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gsubfn package supports string interpolation:

```
library(gsubfn)

Names <- toString( sprintf("%s '%s'", df$name, df$label) )
fn$identity("select $Names from myTable")
```

giving:

```
[1] "select Id 'Record Id', IsDeleted 'Deleted', Name 'ID', Credit__Loan__c 'Loan' from myTable"
```

Here some additional examples: [SO example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714130/sqldf-query-data-by-range-of-dates/25715251#25715251) and [SO example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019532/can-i-use-two-character-vectors-in-a-sqldf-join-statement/23020381#23020381) .

Comment: This works great.  Thanks this is just what I was looking to do.  It even drops the last comma automatically. Many thanks... I am using the query in a non standard sub query language so I needed to control precisely what is the output.

Comment: I am trying to find the documentation for fn$identity. so I can figure out how to use it better.  I did not see it on the CRAN pdf? Did I miss something? The possibilities this opens for my code, I would like to know more. I am looking through the package and wow! thanks...

Comment: Try: `library(gsubfn); ?fn`  Also `vignette(gsubfn)`.  The home page http://gsubfn.googlecode.com has some info too.

Answer (score 2):

```
data(iris)
colnames(iris)
a <- noquote(paste(colnames(iris), collaspe=", "))
as.query.final <- cat("SELECT " , a, " id FROM Credit_Amortization_Schedule__c")
```

The result is:

```
SELECT  Sepal.Length ,  Sepal.Width ,  Petal.Length ,  Petal.Width ,  Species ,   id FROM Credit_Amortization_Schedule__c
```

which you can then use with SQL like this:

```
require(RODBC)
result <- sqlQuery(db, as.query.final)
```

where `db` is your database connection

Or, since I see your `sqldf` tag now, if you want to use `sqldf` it's just:

```
sqldf(as.query.final)
```

Comment: I see that your method prints it to the screen and works, but I do not get it to store the value of the cat into vector call as.query.final.  When I print that vector it is NULL.  Did I miss something

Comment: Oh, okay hmmm I tested it with `sqlQuery` but maybe you're using it differently or something? If you can paste the error/problem you're describing then I will help you fix it